# Is it possible to cycle from Kansai Airport to Central Osaka?

Tags: japan, bicycles, osaka, kix, kansai

I may arrive in Osaka soon with my bicycle to Kansai Airport. Is it possible to cycle from the airport to central Osaka for free?

Answer (score 19):

I'd like to add: no, but *almost*. Here's how you do it:

- Take your bike to the railway station, fold it/disassemble it, and put it into a bag.
- Take the train to Rinkū-Town Station (りんくうタウン駅), which is just one stop away. Either the Nankai Airport Line (南海鉄道空港線) or the JR Kansai Airport Line (JR関西空港線) would work, but be sure not to take the Nankai Limited Express (local or normal express is fine). This will cost you 370 yen.
- From there, you can get to Osaka via Osaka Prefectural Route 204 (大阪府道204号線). I'm sure there are signs on the road that say "Osaka", so just follow that. Remember to cycle on the left.

As it is a normal prefectural route, so bicycles should be allowed. There might even be a bicycle lane. But, in any case, sharing the lane with cars is OK. Just remember not to go on to the expressways.

But of course, if your goal is just to get your bike to downtown Osaka, and you do not really mind paying a bit more, your best choice is probably to just take the train.

Answer (score 13):

No. You can't cycle on the [Hanshin Expressway](https://www.hanshin-exp.co.jp/english/drive/first-time/rules.html), or the Kansai Kuko Highway.

Comment: Useful reference you may want to incorporate: http://www.japancycling.org/v2/info/airport.shtml